# Android Studio Webview with Adressbar and Close button

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I currently have a `webviewer` in my app that works just fine, however, I wanted to see if there was a way to add the `adressbar` and a close button to the top of it. Kinda the same way Instagram does it, see image: [image: Top Adress Bar Instagram]

Right now, I have a close button but when scrolling through the `webview` that close button goes over the content of the website.

My current code:

```
btnOpenWebViewer.setOnClickListener{
        btnCloseWebViewer.visibility = VISIBLE
        webViewer.visibility = VISIBLE
        webViewer.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webViewer.canGoBack()
        webViewer.loadUrl("https://mysite/")
    }
```

Comment: Looks like what you want is Chrome Custom Tab instead of using a WebView. Otherwise you could just add a Toolbar to make a similar UI.

Comment: Yes I found something that worked pretty good! Thanks for the tip (found it here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/chrome-custom-tabs-in-android-with-kotlin/ )

Comment: Oh btw any idea on how to make it fullscreen?

Comment: Chrome Custom Tab is fullscreen

Comment: Well I can clearly see my notification bar at the top.